Are there 105 verses in the Nestle Aland Gospels with 0 manuscript evidence?
I've heard advocates of the Byzantine text claim that Nestle Aland/UBS has over 200 verses in the Gospels alone that have zero manuscript evidence. Has anyone else heard this before? If so, where can one go to find a list?
Update:
The claim is 105 verses, not 200
One example verse that is often cited is Matthew 19:29
The Nestle Aland/UBS is translated into the ESV as such:

And everyone who has left houses or brothers or sisters or father
or mother or children or lands, for my name's sake, will receive a
hundredfold and will inherit eternal life.

However, only one manuscript (Vaticanus) reads the following:

houses or brothers or sisters or father or mother or children or lands

Almost all other manuscripts add "or wife."
However, while many manuscripts (and the NA/UBS) read

will receive a hundredfold (ἑκατονταπλασίονα) and will ...

Vaticanus reads

will receive manifold (πολλαπλασίονα) and will ...

Meaning that the textual critic is making the claim that not a single scribe managed to properly copy this verse down.
Second Update:
I found the source of the claims and it has all the verses listed. Thanks to anyone who may have been searching or trying to help.

Hey Grateful Disciple. I will continue hunting down the claims. As a side note, the Byzantine text is quite different from the TR (KJV). I believe there are roughly 3400 different readings between the two, so I'm not sure KJV-only is a good tag.

The only substantial fact I can provide along these lines is the fact which Dean John Burgon publicised that Codex Sinaiticus and Codex Vaticanus differed from one another in 3,000 places in the gospels alone. See his book The Revision Revised.

Thanks for helping; I found the source article with all the verses listed. I posted an update to the q and an answer as well.

I found the source article written by Dr. M. Robinson.
https://www.christreformedchurch.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/105VersesCT.pdf

105 Verses in the Critical Greek Text of the New Testament Without Any Manuscript Support
These notes were sent to me by Dr. Maurice Robinson and detail 105
places in the Critical Greek Text of the New Testament where the
complete verse reading is not to be found in any Greek manuscript.
This is the result of the reasoned eclectic approach to textual
criticism where readings have been cobbled together from multiple
sources resulting in 105 instances where no single manuscript has the
same reading


This is a bold claim - what is the evidence for this?  There are even more verses in the KJV in a similar situation.

"readings have been cobbled together from multiple sources resulting in 105 instances where no single manuscript has the same reading" that is not at all the same as 0 manuscript evidence. Remember that the verse breaks are modern divisions. Having one sentence of phrase come from one source and another sentence or phrase come from another source doesn't mean the whole thing has no evidence.

In the April to June 2007 edition of The Trinitarian Bible Society's Quarterly Record, there is a 23-page article about the German 'higher critic' who is the 'Aland' of the Nestle-Aland Greek 26th edition and the United Bible Societies (UBS) 1966 and 1983 Greek texts of the New Testament.
I looked for any mention of 105 verses that might have had zero manuscript evidence / support, but no such number appeared. What did appear, however, was insight into why his text differs so radically from the previous Textus Receptus in the Greek for the New Testament. As the o.p. has now provided the source that was being looked for, this answer is to provide reasons as to why there were not only additions, but omissions from the Greek text in Aland's work, concluding with a further source worth checking out.
Born in Berlin in 1915, Kurt Aland died in 1994. The most famous modern English versions of the New Testament - the Revised Standard Version, the New American Standard Version, the New International Version, and the English Standard Version - are all grounded on, and, for the most part, translated from Aland's work. As the TBS article says:

"These translations utilise as their principle text (with its critical
apparatus and alternate readings) the United Bible Societies version
of the Greek New Testament, a version over which Dr Aland was a
principal editor. Indeed, the UBS version third edition (1983) is
virtually the same as Aland's own twenty-sixth edition of the
Nestle-Aland text: such was his influence over the UBS text...
At present, the NIV and the ESV are sweeping evangelical churches in
the United States and Britain. Thus, modern churchgoers are being
profoundly influenced by Aland's Greek Text, and so also by his
peculiar views of the text. This is because the very verses that
modern churchgoers are reading in their Bibles reflect the theological
and textual views of Dr Aland, which underlie his choices for readings
and variant readings for every verse in the original Greek...
We come then to the point of this paper, namely to show concerned
readers what Kurt Aland's theological views are concerning Biblical
inspiration, inerrancy, and infallibility." (Ibid, p. 17-18)

The article then turns to three of Aland's works, first, The Problem of Anonymity and Pseudonymity in Christian Literature of the First Two Cenurties, then A History of Christianity, and third The Problem, of the New Testament Canon See also The Text of the New Testament by Kurt and Barbara Aland, translated in 1995, Eerdmans
Examples are taken from Aland's writings to show why his text is at variance so often with the Received Text. His rejection of early Church standards re. the canon, the authorship of and the inspiration of New Testament writings mean that Aland looked to "modern scientific knowledge" as superior to how the third century Church was "working with inadequate standards of discrimination" so that they ought to have deleted several books from the canon of the N.T. [quotes around Aland's wording]. The TBS article continues:

"To summarise then: the texts on which Dr Aland relies were rejected
by the historic Church because of their known poor quality (high
number of spelling and historical errors), or their known parentage
from texts that had been corrupted by heretics (as were the so-called
Alexandrian texts, which came from upper Egypt, where the Gnostic
errorists proliferated.) These texts, rejected by the historic Church,
are the ones that Dr Aland relies upon." (Ibid. p.28)

Also, Dr Aland himself admits that he systematically rejected all texts of the Byzantine tradition - the tradition from which Textus Receptus arose. On page xvii of the Introduction to the UBS text of 1966 that point is stated by the UBS. Out of 1,000 manuscripts a selection of miniscules showing any marks of being in the Byzantine tradition "were intentionally omitted from consideration".
This, I would expect, would be a source for calculating whether 105 manuscript omissions to Aland's text came from those deliberately omitted miniscules. That would be page xvii of the Introduction to the UBS text of 1966, where those omitted texts are listed. Aland listed three manuscripts extant from Papias's time which date around A.D. 200, after Papias. Three manuscripts are not a statistically significant sampling of the period. But there are more mentioned (Ibid. p.31). The article (by A. Hembd) should be available in digital format from The Trinitarian Bible Society http://www.trinitarianbiblesociety.org
